# jQuery slider output

Tags: jquery, slider, output

I have this strange problem. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6qJC/7/

And as you can see, it should take value of a first slider, then the second one, do some calculating and print result. BUT, when you move slider (the first one, the second is not doing it ) fast, to the one end or another, it calculates weird things. Have a look pls. Is there a solution pls?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#amount_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 500,
        max: 4999,
        value: 500,
        step: 10,
                animate: 'slow',
                slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);
            calculate();
        }
    });
    $("#time_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 7,
        max: 28,
                step: 7,
        value: 7,
                animate: true,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#timeDisp").text(ui.value);
            calculate();
        }
    });
    function calculate() {
        var amount = parseInt($("#amount_slider").slider("value"));
        var time = parseInt($("#time_slider").slider("value"));
                var coeficient = 0;
                switch(time){
                       case 7: coeficient = 1.09;break;
                       case 14: coeficient = 1.15;break;
                       case 21: coeficient = 1.19;break;
                       case 28: coeficient = 1.25;break;
                       }
        var rate = amount * coeficient;
        $("#result").text(rate.toFixed(2));
    }   
});
```

and html:

```
<p>Money: <span id="amountDisp">500</span><div id="amount_slider"></div></p><p>Time: <span id="timeDisp">7</span><div id="time_slider"></div></p><p>Calculated <span id="result">545</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider's value has not been updated yet at the point where you use `.slider("value")` to fetch it. It updates only after the slide event has finished so the calculation uses the previous value instead of the current one.

A quick fix is to pass the values as parameters:

```
// in the amount slider event
calculate(parseInt(ui.value, 10), parseInt($("#time_slider").slider("value"), 10));

// in the time slider event
calculate(parseInt($("#amount_slider").slider("value"), 10), parseInt(ui.value, 10));

function calculate(amount, time) {
   ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6qJC/9/